# Jekyll Folder Structure. Having folders/lists on a page which each have specific posts

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I have a page called blog.md which has some code like this.

```
permalink: /blog/
layout: collection
collection: blog
entries_layout: grid
classes: wide
```

Then I have a folder called _blog, with a number of .md files in.

Is there anyway I can add another level of order here and instead of displaying all the _blog .md files on the blog.md page.. I want to add two folders/lists which contain certain .md files.

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work by adding the path to your `for` loop. For example, let's assume you have a directory in your `_blog` directory called "orange." So your file path would be `_blog/orange`. To loop through only the files in the `orange` directory you could do this:

```liquid
{% for post in site.blog.orange %}
  {{ post.do-stuff }}
{% endfor %}
```

On a side note, Jekyll is going to look for blog posts in the `_posts` directory. I assume this `_blog` directory is a collection, but creating a "blog" collection will make things confusing if anyone else ever needs to touch this codebase.

Comment: Hi there, thank you for your comments. Yes it is a collection. I thought this way would work best so that it would separate my posts which are more project based to my blog posts. There may have been a better way to do this but it works nicely for separation and clarity, is there any way I can group collections. Say I have blog posts from march to june. Can I group them based on this maybe? So all from march go in some _blog/march and so on? Cheers for the help again.

Comment: If you had a directory structure of `_blog/march`, you'd replace `site.blog.orange` with `site.blog.march` in the above example.